Not able to generate the java code of xtend files using gradle xtend plugin
I am trying to build the project with gradle and it has xtend code. I have applied the xtend and xtext builder plugins, Below is the snippet of build.gradle which i tried. But not able to generate the java code for the xtend classes.
gradle wrapper version : 7.3.3. Below i have attached the project structure

Can some one help me to resolve the issue ?
plugins {
  id "org.xtext.xtend"  version "2.0.7"
  id 'org.xtext.builder' version '2.0.7'
  id "java-library"
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.lib:2.17.1'
 xtextLanguages 'org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.core:2.17.1'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src','xtend-gen']
    main.xtendOutputDir = 'xtend-gen'
  }
  
xtext {
    languages {
      mapy {
        setup = 'com.mchp.mapy.MapyStandaloneSetup'
        generator.outlet.producesJava = true
      }
    }
    
  }
xtend {
    generator {
      //whether to generate @SuppressWarnings("all"), enabled by default
      suppressWarningsAnnotation = false
      //whether to generate the @Generated annotation, disabled by default
      generatedAnnotation {
        active = true
        comment = "Copyright My Cool Company"
        includeDate = true
      }
    }
    debugger {
      //how to install debug info into generated Java code
      //SMAP adds Xtend debug info on top of Java
      //PRIMARY makes Xtend the only debug info (throws away Java line numbers)
      //default is SMAP
      sourceInstaller = 'SMAP' //or 'PRIMARY' or 'NONE'
      //whether to hide synthetic variables in the debugger
      hideSyntheticVariables = true
    }
    validator {
      //adjust severity of issues
      //available levels are error, warning, info and ignore
      error 'org.eclipse.xtend.core.validation.IssueCodes.unused_private_member'
      // These issue IDs can be found in your Eclipse project's .settings/org.eclipse.xtend.core.Xtend.prefs
      // after enabling Project > Properties > Xtend > Errors/Warnings: [X] Enable project specific settings
    }
  }
 
tasks.withType(org.xtext.gradle.tasks.XtextGenerate) {
    bootstrapClasspath = configurations.compileClasspath
   
    languages = [xtext.languages.mapy]
    sources = sourceSets.main.xtend
}



What is the error you're getting?

I'm getting compilation issues as xtend code has not been generated into java source code.
